# Alternative of finding theta when sin $\theta$ and cos $\theta$ are given

Tags: trigonometry

For example, we're given a problem in which sin $\theta = \sqrt3/2$ and cos $\theta = -1/2$. To find out the angle $\theta$, I look at the unit circle and I get the answer. However, I was just curious whether there's an alternative to this, any idea? Because when I tried using cos(-$\theta$) = cos$\theta$, I get the wrong value of $\theta$ as we've been provided with the value of sin $\theta$ as well...

Comment: Why duplicating your question of yesterday:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929151/find-out-theta-when-sin-thetas-and-cos-thetas-value-are-given  ?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Sorry, no idea why I did that!

Comment: any help here, if you can, will be really appreciated: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16259/how-does-k2cr2o7-become-cr2o7-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sin\theta=\frac{\sqrt3}2=\sin\frac\pi3\implies\theta=n\pi+(-1)^n\frac\pi3$$
where $n$ is any integer

Set $n=2s+1,$(odd) $=2s$(even) one by one

Again,
$$\cos\theta=-\frac12=-\cos\frac\pi3=\cos\left(\pi-\frac\pi3\right)$$
$$\implies\theta=2m\pi\pm\left(\pi-\frac\pi3\right)$$
where $m$ is any integer

Check for '+','-' one by one

Observe that the intersection of the above two solutions is $$\theta=2r\pi+\frac{2\pi}3$$
where $r$ is any integer

Answer (score 1):

The given data determine $\theta$ up to an additive multiple of $2\pi$. When $\cos\theta\ne-1$ the principal value $\theta\in\ ]{-\pi},\pi[\ $  can be found using the formula
$$\tan{\theta\over2}={\sin\theta\over 1+\cos\theta}\ ,$$
which leads to
$$\theta=2\arctan{\sin\theta\over 1+\cos\theta}\ .$$
In your example we get
$$\theta=2\arctan{{\sqrt{3}\over2}\over 1-{1\over2}}=2\arctan\sqrt{3}={2\pi\over3}\ .$$